# I'm having this error called `'float' object is not iterable` even after i replaced all the digits in my dataset with spaces

Tags: python, regex, pandas, nlp, dataset

I have a dataset where a column contains digits and sentences mixed up however i want to remove those and Remove all punctuation,Remove all stopwords and Return a list of the cleaned text

I have tried using regex to replace the digits with spaces.

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import re

df = pd.read_excel("samplefinal.xlsx")
df['comments'] = df['comments'].str.replace(r'\d+','')
mess = df["comments"]

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def text_process(mess):
    nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in string.punctuation]

    nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)

    return [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in
    stopwords.words('english')]
```

`df["comments"].apply(text_process)`

data:

```
    ID             Name                    comments

   28930           poil              The host canceled this reservation 24 
                                    days 
                                    before arrival. This is an automated 
                                    posting.

   7389             opil            This apartment is very clean and is 
                                    perfect for 2,  is 10 mins walking 
                                    from the Tabata
```

error message on using the above code: 
'''

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
    last)
    <ipython-input-22-ab6d2299296f> in <module>
    ----> 1 df["comments"].apply(text_process)

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, 
    convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
     3589             else:
     3590                 values = self.astype(object).values
   ->3591                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, 
    convert=convert_dtype)
     3592 
     3593         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

     pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

     <ipython-input-21-971b567ffb47> in text_process(mess)
           1 def text_process(mess):
     ----> 2  nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in 
           string.punctuation]
           3 #nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in 
           string.punctuation]
           4 nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)
           5 return [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in 
            stopwords.words('english')]

            TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

'''
expectation:

```
   ID             Name                    comments

   28930           poil             [host, canceled, reservation, 
                                    days,
                                    before, arrival, automated 
                                    posting

   7389             opil            [apartment,clean, 
                                    perfect, mins, walking 
                                    Tabata
```

I might be wrong with the expected output because i'm not aware of all the stopwords present but i hope you get the idea. Please help!

Comment: Try rerunning with `mess = df["comments"].values` instead. How exactly are you calling the function `text_process`?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is. Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Your column has NaNs, couldn't you have figured this out by now? Your previous questions also required answers that handled NaNs appropriately.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler I have updated how I am calling the text_process function. Also the entire error message.

Comment: @John Gordon I am sorry i have updated the full error traceback message. Please help if possible.

Comment: @cs95 I have this data with 260,000 records i dont know if the data has NaNs, How should i go about it?

Comment: `print(df['comments'].isnull().any())` should return True.

Comment: yeah! It did so should i replace those with some characters to get desired result?

Comment: @cs95 Also i thought there were some float objects that were creating this issue?

Comment: type(np.NaN) is float. Yes, replace them or drop the rows via dropna().

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with loading your data, or how you use `text_process`, because given the example you supplied us, your original code works perfectly.

I tried:

```py
import pandas as pd
import string
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [28930, 7389], 'Name': ['poil', 'opil'], 'comments': [
    'The host canceled this reservation 24 days before arrival. This is an automated posting.',
    'This apartment is very clean and is perfect for 2,  is 10 mins walking from the Tabata']})

df['comments'] = df['comments'].str.replace(r'\d+', '')
mess = df["comments"]

from nltk.corpus import stopwords


def text_process(mess):
    nopunc = [char for char in mess if char not in string.punctuation]

    nopunc = ''.join(nopunc)

    return [word for word in nopunc.split() if word.lower() not in
            stopwords.words('english')]


print("DATA:")
print(df)

print("RESULTS:")
for row in mess:
    print(text_process(row))
```

and got:

```
DATA:
      ID  Name                                           comments
0  28930  poil  The host canceled this reservation  days befor...
1   7389  opil  This apartment is very clean and is perfect fo...
RESULTS:
['host', 'canceled', 'reservation', 'days', 'arrival', 'automated', 'posting']
['apartment', 'clean', 'perfect', 'mins', 'walking', 'Tabata']
```

can you please add to the question the code that actually calls `text_process`? maybe you somehow pass a float arg instead of a string message?

maybe add `print(type(mess))` as the 1st line of the function to see when it is a `float`

Comment: Hey @Adam.Er8 I have updated the code with line where it actually calls text_process. Also I checked with print(type(mess)). It gives me this

Comment: .............                                                                                       

 It goes on to print millions of this `<class str'>` then throws this `<class 'float'>`  and gives the above error. I knew that i have float values in my text that's why i replaced it with ' ', it I dont know what else should i try?